# How to upgrade scrapy to latest version

Tags: python, scrapy

[image: screen Short of cmd]
Q:how to upgrade scrapy?

I have run the cmd as administrator,use the command "pip install --upgrade scrapy"
and get result as 'Access is denied'

I am using windows 7.

Is there any way to upgrade scrapy.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have came across this dilemma a couple of times. First:

1. Restart your machine and try again without opening anything but the
   CMD in admin.
2. If that fails try updating pip:

   `easy_install -U pip`

   **or**

   `pip install --upgrade pip`
3. If this too doesn't work...

   `pip install --upgrade pip`

   `pip uninstall scrapy`

   `pip install scrapy`

Comment: thanks @ham-sandwich.This solves the problem.For re-installation I have used "easy_install scrapy".this installs correctly

Comment: @Deep3015 I was unaware you could use `easy_install` for Scrapy. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I had trouble upgrading from 0.24 to 1.01.  I have to uninstall and then install scrapy as suggested above.  Thanks!